# Is there any joke exist in Livre's words?

Tags: meaning, jokes

In *The Old Guard (2020)*, Freeman sees a statue of Rodin in Immortal Andy's caves:

Freeman: This is an honest-to-God Rodin. Wait. Did you know
him?

Livre: **Probably biblically**.

(Livre & Andy laughs)

Is there any joke exist in Livre's words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old versions of the Christian Bible sometimes used the verb 'know' to mean 'have sex with'.

> And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and
> said, I have gotten a man from the Lord. (King James Version)
>
> Later, Adam had sexual relations with his wife Eve. She became
> pregnant and gave birth to Cain. She said, “I have given birth to a
> male child—the Lord. (International Standard Version)
>
> [Book of Genesis, chapter 4, verse 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%204&version=ISV)

It is a common joke among English speakers, if asked if they know, or knew,  someone of any gender, to say 'not biblically', or 'not in the biblical sense'. The joke is considered funnier if the person is someone with whom the joker would obviously not ever have sex.

[Know someone in the biblical sense](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/know_someone_in_the_biblical_sense#:%7E:text=From%20the%20use%20of%20know,wife%3B%20and%20she%20conceived.%22)